# How to create website with mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am having a MuOnline server. it's not a business server just a free server so friends on the forum can come in and have fun.i want to create a website where people can freely sign up for an account. because now people have to contact me so I can create an account for them (sometimes I'm not online so I can't create an account for them right away). every mu online server is built database on SQL Server. but the server I'm using is MySQL again. so I can't use those website templates to link to my mysql.i just need simple website. Just register and download the game.my server mu and data mysql is running on vps cloud. Looking forward to your help. thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

You have posted on the wrong website - https://www.upwork.com would be more suitable for your post.